# Is there any way to change default block setting of pop-ups and redirect to allow in chrome using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to allow the Pop-ups and redirect setting of chrome using selenium java. Is there any way?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In pop-ups logic we have to mention below logic,

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String url = " https://www.google.com"; 
driver.get(url);
```

For more clarification please gothrough the link[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-launch-chrome-browser-via-selenium) first example